Enviar por bluetooth archivo .txt desde un ESP32 con su modulo de tarjeta SD a PC con programa en C#
Tengo problemas para lograr importar un archivo .txt completo desde mi ESP32 y guardarlo en mi PC. Hice una prueba externa con SerialBluetoothTerminal y veo que el contenido del archivo si se muestra pero linea por linea, al parecer el el codigo c# no se esta agrupando correctamente, Por otro lado, la terminal serial del IDE de arduino (que es donde estoy programando el ESP) si muestra confirmacion de envio, aunque quiza tambien puede que este enviando mal el archivo... adjunto codigos.
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth;
using InTheHand.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace PST_1._0
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        BluetoothClient bluetoothClient;
        BluetoothDeviceInfo selectedDevice;
        BluetoothClient connectedClient; // Cliente Bluetooth para la conexión
        Thread readThread;
        bool keepReading;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            bluetoothClient = new BluetoothClient();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillBluetoothDevicesComboBox();
        }

        private void FillBluetoothDevicesComboBox()
        {
            comboBoxBluetoothDevices.Items.Clear();

            try
            {

                var devices = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices(); // Obtenemos los dispositivos como IReadOnlyCollection

                foreach (BluetoothDeviceInfo device in devices)
                {
                    comboBoxBluetoothDevices.Items.Add(device.DeviceName);
                }

                if (comboBoxBluetoothDevices.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    comboBoxBluetoothDevices.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    comboBoxBluetoothDevices.Items.Add("No se encontraron dispositivos Bluetooth");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al buscar dispositivos Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void btnConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (comboBoxBluetoothDevices.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string selectedDeviceName = comboBoxBluetoothDevices.SelectedItem.ToString();
                var devices = bluetoothClient.DiscoverDevices();
                selectedDevice = devices.FirstOrDefault(device => device.DeviceName == selectedDeviceName);

                if (selectedDevice != null)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        connectedClient = new BluetoothClient();
                        connectedClient.Connect(selectedDevice.DeviceAddress, BluetoothService.SerialPort);

                        MessageBox.Show("Conexión establecida con el dispositivo.");

                        keepReading = true;
                        readThread = new Thread(ReadData);
                        readThread.Start();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error al conectar al dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El dispositivo seleccionado no está disponible.");
                }


            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No se ha seleccionado ningún dispositivo.");
            }
        }

        private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectedClient != null && connectedClient.Connected)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(connectedClient.GetStream());
                    writer.Write("ON");
                    writer.Flush();

                    MessageBox.Show("Se envió el carácter 'A' al dispositivo.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay una conexión activa con el dispositivo Bluetooth.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al enviar datos al dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //boton desconectar
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectedClient != null && connectedClient.Connected)
                {
                    keepReading = false; // Detiene la lectura de datos
                    connectedClient.Close();
                    MessageBox.Show("Desconexión exitosa del dispositivo Bluetooth.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay ninguna conexión activa para desconectar.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al desconectar del dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BOTON ENVIAR OFF
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectedClient != null && connectedClient.Connected)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(connectedClient.GetStream());
                    writer.Write("OFF");
                    writer.Flush();

                    MessageBox.Show("Se envió el carácter 'OFF' al dispositivo.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay una conexión activa con el dispositivo Bluetooth.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al enviar datos al dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //BOTON DE ENVIAR STATUS
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectedClient != null && connectedClient.Connected)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(connectedClient.GetStream());
                    writer.Write("STATUS");
                    writer.Flush();

                    MessageBox.Show("Se envió el carácter 'STATUS' al dispositivo.");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay una conexión activa con el dispositivo Bluetooth.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al enviar datos al dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void ReadData()
        {
            try
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(connectedClient.GetStream());

                while (keepReading)
                {
                    string receivedData = reader.ReadLine(); // Leer una línea de datos

                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedData))
                    {
                        // Usar Invoke para actualizar la UI desde el hilo de lectura
                        this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                        {
                            richTextBox1.AppendText(receivedData + Environment.NewLine);
                        }));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                this.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error al leer datos del dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
                }));
            }
        }

        private void btnReceiveFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (connectedClient != null && connectedClient.Connected)
                {
                    StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(connectedClient.GetStream());
                    writer.Write("GET_FILE\n");
                    writer.Flush();

                    NetworkStream ns = connectedClient.GetStream();
                    List<byte> fileBytes = new List<byte>();
                    bool isReceivingFile = false;

                    while (true)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
                        int bytesRead = ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (bytesRead == 0) break;

                        string line = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                        if (line.Contains("START_OF_FILE"))
                        {
                            isReceivingFile = true;
                            fileBytes.Clear(); // Iniciar la recepción de un nuevo archivo
                        }
                        else if (line.Contains("END_OF_FILE"))
                        {
                            isReceivingFile = false;
                            SaveFileToDisk(fileBytes.ToArray());
                            MessageBox.Show("Archivo recibido y guardado exitosamente.");
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (isReceivingFile)
                        {
                            fileBytes.AddRange(buffer.Take(bytesRead));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No hay una conexión activa con el dispositivo Bluetooth.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error al recibir el archivo desde el dispositivo Bluetooth: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void SaveFileToDisk(Byte[] fileBytes)
        {
            using (SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
            {
                saveFileDialog.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
                saveFileDialog.Title = "Guardar archivo de datos";
                saveFileDialog.FileName = "interacciones.txt"; // Nombre de archivo

                if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    string filePath = saveFileDialog.FileName;

                    try
                    {
                        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, fileBytes);
                        MessageBox.Show("Archivo guardado en " + filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Error al guardar el archivo: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

A continuacion el codigo del ESP32:
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_Sensor.h>
#include <Adafruit_BME280.h>
#include <RTClib.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <BluetoothSerial.h>

// Crear un objeto para el sensor BME280
Adafruit_BME280 bme;

// Crear un objeto para el módulo DS1307
RTC_DS1307 rtc;

// Crear un objeto para manejar la comunicación Bluetooth
BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

// Pin del módulo SD
const int chipSelect = 5;

// Nombre del archivo en la tarjeta SD
const char* filename = "/interacciones.txt";

// Pin del LED
const int ledPin = 2;

// Variable para almacenar el valor de la presión en altura (opcional)
const float SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA = 1013.25;

// Variable para controlar el tiempo de muestreo
unsigned long previousMillis = 0;
const long interval = 5000;  // Intervalo de 5 segundos

void setup() {
  // Iniciar la comunicación serie
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Iniciar la comunicación Bluetooth
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32_Bluetooth"); // Nombre del dispositivo Bluetooth
  Serial.println("El dispositivo Bluetooth está listo para emparejarse.");

  // Configurar el pin del LED como salida
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW); // Asegurarse de que el LED esté apagado al inicio

  // Iniciar la comunicación I2C
  Wire.begin();

  // Iniciar el sensor BME280
  if (!bme.begin(0x76)) {   // La dirección I2C común del BME280 es 0x76 o 0x77
    Serial.println("No se encontró el sensor BME280, verifique la conexión.");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Sensor BME280 inicializado con éxito.");

  // Iniciar el módulo DS1307
  if (!rtc.begin()) {
    Serial.println("No se encontró el módulo DS1307, verifique la conexión.");
    while (1);
  }
  
  // Si el RTC no está en marcha, lo iniciamos
  if (!rtc.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("El reloj no está funcionando, se establecerá la hora.");
    rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
  }

  // Iniciar el módulo SD
  if (!SD.begin(chipSelect)) {
    Serial.println("No se pudo inicializar la tarjeta SD.");
    while (1);
  }
  Serial.println("Tarjeta SD inicializada con éxito.");
}

void loop() {
  // Obtener el tiempo actual
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();

  // Verificar si han pasado 5 segundos
  if (currentMillis - previousMillis >= interval) {
    // Guardar el tiempo actual para la próxima comparación
    previousMillis = currentMillis;

    // Leer datos del sensor BME280
    float temperature = bme.readTemperature();
    float pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
    float altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
    float humidity = bme.readHumidity();

    // Leer la fecha y hora del RTC
    DateTime now = rtc.now();

    // Modificar la cadena de datos guardados en la SD para usar el formato CSV
    String dataString = "";
    dataString += String(now.year()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.day()) + ",";
    dataString += String(now.hour()) + ":" + String(now.minute()) + ":" + String(now.second()) + ",";
    dataString += String(temperature) + ",";
    dataString += String(pressure) + ",";
    dataString += String(altitude) + ",";
    dataString += String(humidity);

    // Abrir el archivo en modo de añadir (append)
    File dataFile = SD.open(filename, FILE_APPEND);

    // Si el archivo está disponible, escribir los datos
    if (dataFile) {
    // Si es la primera vez que escribimos en el archivo, agregar los encabezados
      if (dataFile.size() == 0) {
        dataFile.println("Fecha,Hora,Temperatura (°C),Presión (hPa),Altitud (m),Humedad (%)");
      }

      dataFile.println(dataString);
      dataFile.close();
      Serial.println("Datos guardados: ");
      Serial.println(dataString);
    } else {
      Serial.println("Error al abrir el archivo.");
      }
  }

  // Escuchar datos recibidos por Bluetooth
  if (SerialBT.available()) {
    String command = SerialBT.readStringUntil('\n');
    command.trim();  // Eliminar espacios en blanco adicionales

    if (command == "ON") {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
      SerialBT.println("LED encendido");
    } else if (command == "OFF") {
      digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      SerialBT.println("LED apagado");
    } else if (command == "STATUS") {
      // Leer datos del sensor BME280
      float temperature = bme.readTemperature();
      float pressure = bme.readPressure() / 100.0F;
      float altitude = bme.readAltitude(SEALEVELPRESSURE_HPA);
      float humidity = bme.readHumidity();

      // Leer la fecha y hora del RTC
      DateTime now = rtc.now();

      // Crear un objeto JSON en forma de cadena
      String jsonString = "{";
      jsonString += "\"Fecha\":\"" + String(now.year()) + "-" + String(now.month()) + "-" + String(now.day()) + "\",";
      jsonString += "\"Hora\":\"" + String(now.hour()) + ":" + String(now.minute()) + ":" + String(now.second()) + "\",";
      jsonString += "\"Temperatura\":\"" + String(temperature) + "\",";
      jsonString += "\"Presión\":\"" + String(pressure) + "\",";
      jsonString += "\"Altitud\":\"" + String(altitude) + "\",";
      jsonString += "\"Humedad\":\"" + String(humidity) + "\"";
      jsonString += "}";

      // Enviar la información en formato JSON a través de Bluetooth
      SerialBT.println(jsonString);
    } 
    else if (command == "GET_FILE") {
      sendFileOverBluetooth();
    }
    else {
      SerialBT.println("Comando no reconocido");
    }
  }

  // Aquí puedes agregar otras funciones que necesiten ejecutarse continuamente
}

void sendFileOverBluetooth() {
    File dataFile = SD.open(filename);
    if (dataFile) {
        SerialBT.println("START_OF_FILE");
        Serial.println("Enviando archivo...");

        while (dataFile.available()) {
            uint8_t buffer[64];  // Envía el archivo en trozos de 64 bytes
            size_t bytesRead = dataFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            SerialBT.write(buffer, bytesRead);  // Enviar bytes en binario
        }

        SerialBT.println("END_OF_FILE");
        Serial.println("Archivo enviado.");
        dataFile.close();
    } else {
        SerialBT.println("Error al abrir el archivo.");
        Serial.println("Error al abrir el archivo.");
    }
}

Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias.

El primer problema que veo es que loop() hace una cantidad infinita de cosas en cada invocación, como enviar el archivo completo de una sola vez, lo que puede generar todo tipo de errores. Lo primero que debe hacer es reescribir el código de modo que loop haga sólo una cosa en cada invocación. Por ejemplo, enviar una línea del archivo cad vez.
